# How do I install a Web Application to the root of the domain using Plesk?

Tags: plesk

I'm trying to use Parallels Plesk Panel 9.5.5 for Windows, and I'm trying to install Mediawiki using their installer. I want the wiki to be on the root of the domain, but I can't figure out what to put in this field

[image: Plesk]

I found similiar questions on different sites that suggested using `.` or `/` and neither worked. `httpdocs` just placed an `httpdocs` folder inside the exisitng `httpdocs` folder. This is a required field so I can't leave it blank. It seems like this should be possible, any ideas?

Comment: Installing in the domain root is not a good idea. What you're probably looking for is short URL configuration. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Plesk used to have an option called "Install to Document Root". That option doesn't exist anymore, and so we're not allowed/able to install to the home directory. We'd have to do a manual install.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to try and find out the real directory on the file system. For example the root of our shared hosting is actually in /home/*companyname*. This info might be in the support info from your hosting company, or you might see it somewhere in Plesk.